# How to open "http://localhost:8081/" in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I started a new project in google could datalab. I closed the project, but now I want to re-open the project "http://localhost:8081/" and run my code. However, I don't know what I had done when I created the project. Procedures were so complicated and I don't know what steps I did until I created a project and run my python code. I would be thankful if someone can explain how it is possible to open the project in google cloud datalab.

Comment: Where are your starting your datalab instance? On your local environment? or on Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 1):

When you created the Datalab instance, a new persistent disk was created as well to support it.

If you did not remove it, you can initialize a new instance with that persistent disk:

```sh
datalab create datalab-instance-name --disk-name datalab-persistent-disk
```

Please, see the relevant [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create#--disk-name_disk_name).

You can look for the disk name in the `Disks` section of the Compute Engine console.